# Change of variable Technique

Tags: probability

Which transformation will change a r.v $X$ with pdf is as below to a uniform r.v. $Y$ whose range is $0\le y\le 1$:

a) $
f(x)=\begin{cases}
2 \mathrm e^{-2x} & x\ge 0\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

b) $f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac12(x-3) & 3\le x\le 5\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ a continuous random variable whose distribution function $F_X$ is strictly increasing on the possible values of $X$. Then $F_X$ has an inverse function.
Let $Y = F_X(X)$, then for $y\in [0,1]$,
$$
\Bbb P\{Y\le y\} = \Bbb P\{F_X(X) \le y\} = \Bbb P\{Y\le F^{−1}_X(y)\} = F_X(F^{−1}_X(y)) = y.
$$
In other words, $Y$ is a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$.

So we have for a) and b):
$$
f_a(x)=\begin{cases}
2 \mathrm e^{-2x} & x\ge 0\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad F_a(x)=\begin{cases}
1- \mathrm e^{-2x} & x\ge 0\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
So $Y=F_a(X)\sim\mathsf{Uniform}(0,1)$.

$$
f_b(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac12(x-3) & 3\le x\le 5\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad F_a(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x\le 3\\
\frac14(x-3)^2 & 3\le x\le 5\\
1& x\ge 5
\end{cases}
$$
So $Y=F_b(X)\sim\mathsf{Uniform}(0,1)$